# What is the users object in npm registry json response?

Tags: javascript, npm, jsonschema, npm-registry

For the json response for any npm package. In jQuery for example, `http://registry.npmjs.org/jquery` there exists a dictionary `users` with some usernames as keys and a boolean value as the value.

```
"users": {
    "dodo": true,
    "fgribreau": true,
    "parroit": true,
    "cedx": true,
    "bendiken": true,
    "funroll": true
}
```

What is this user dictionary? I couldn't find any reference about it. If someone could explain?

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [npm registry docs](https://github.com/npm/registry/blob/master/docs/responses/package-metadata.md#full-metadata-format)

> `users` an object whose keys are the npm user names of people who have starred this package

A description for what starring is can be found [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/star)

> "Starring" a package means that you have some interest in it. It's a vaguely positive way to show that you care.
>
> "Unstarring" is the same thing, but in reverse.
>
> It's a boolean thing. Starring repeatedly has no additional effect.